# AureliaJS app duplicated on all browser tabs

Tags: google-chrome, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia JS skeleton for TS and JSPM from github as a started app and as I was playing with it and opened a second browser tab to compare data on different pages. But as I worked in one tab, what I did was duplicated on the other tab. So I opened an incognito tab and tried that. It did the same thing! Is there a way to configure it so that I can have a different view on each tab within the same app?

Comment: How are you running the app/web server from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsersync does this, you can turn off things like mirroring when you surf to `localhost:3001` (this is the default url for the Aurelia CLI, so it could be different in your setup)

Answer (score 0):

when running the skeleton you can disable the browsersync feature you are seeing by simply running `gulp serve` instead of `gulp watch` from the terminal